# How to get rid of title bar during app start

Tags: android

When my app starts it shows a title bar with the app icon before the actual layouting of my main activity is being displayed.

How do I get rid of that title bar?

I have a custom title bar (e.g. `ActionBar`) that I use for my application but this is only setup during the `onCreate` method of my activity.
If I add style `NoTitleBar` to the Manifest I am getting NullPointerException when accessing using `getActionBar` in the main activity in order to set my custom action bar.
Having

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in the `onCreate` method does not help as it comes too late.

Comment: The titlebar is the actionbar. You cannot simultaneously have and not have it.

Comment: I want it. But I want it only for the layout of my activities not during the app start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In you manifest set the activity theme to Theme.noTitleBar

   ```
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
   ```
2. In your activity onCreate method do the following:

   ```
   // Apply default theme to your activity.
   setTheme(R.style.YourAppTheme);
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   // Make sure action bar can be used.
   supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

   // Optionally, hide action bar from the screen (For example, login screen might have action bar hidden);
   // getSupportActionBar().hide();

   // Apply your layout here.
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   ```